# Is there a way to dynamically create and dispose of Webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, dispose, instantiation

I have this App that uses the Webbrowser control to do automated browsing. I need to come up with a way to automatically close the browser (dispose), then create another instance that actually works.

Here's some of the code that I have so far.

```
this.webBrowser2 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
this.webBrowser2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
this.webBrowser2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 34);
this.webBrowser2.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
this.webBrowser2.Name = "webBrowser2";
this.webBrowser2.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
this.webBrowser2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(616, 447);
this.webBrowser2.TabIndex = 1;
```

So I was thinking if I dispose of the webbrower instance.

```
webBrowser2.dispose();
```

And then creating a new instance of the webbrowser object.

```
WebBrowser w = new WebBroswer();
w.Navigate(url);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The new instance of the browser doesn't show up and the disposed browser object just stays frozen in the windows form.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more of why you want to do that?  What is the advantage of destroying the first browser?  Why not just use webBrowser2.Navigate again and again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add and remove the WebBrowsers from the form's Controls property:

```
this.Controls.Remove(webBrowser2);
this.Controls.Add(w);
```

If you get stuck, there's also [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319266) that has an *almost* complete walkthrough to adding and removing controls (it doesn't include much about events).

Comment: Wow, okay this looks like the answer, thanks. I am going to test it out real quick